# Namespaces not recognized in ASP.NET 5 MVC6 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying out ASP.NET 5 with MVC 6 but have some issues.
Using Visual Studio 2015 Comm

I create a model under namespace MyApp.wwwroot.Models.
Then a service under namespace MyApp.wwwroot.Service. Here I reference my model. It just shows in black, not in blue. It also has no quick actions or squigly line. When I build it says "Build Succeeded". I have the same problem when I add a reference to Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc in my Controller. When I create a new controller and inherit from Controller. I have the same issue..

Is this VS or what could be the issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to place code under the `wwwroot` folder.  The `wwwroot` folder in ASP.Net Core (formerly ASP.Net 5) is used for hosting static content and these files are not parsed or compiled as C# code, but rather as static content that you want served (ex. html/css/javascript files).  Moving these files out of the `wwwroot` folder should fix this issue if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

When working in your FishtankApp.Services namespace, you need to expose your model namespace.  this is done by adding the following using declaration at the top of the source code document you wish to use it on:

```
  using FishTankApp.Models ;
```

The same holds true for anything you wish to use that falls outside the scope of the current namespace you're working in.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I know I need to do this. As you can see in the first screenshot I've done this for the services. The problem is that VS does not seem to recognize my namespaces. Kr

Comment: Correct, but the using you have in your snipit would only expose the 'Services', not 'Models'.  to use both, they both have to be exposed with using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added new images. As you can see the usings are there. The problem is VS does not recognize them or resolve classes in the namespaces as you can see in image 3. It does not color blue the class: IntHistoryModel

Comment: Try using the fully qualified class name to verify you have all the namespace components. I.E IEnumerable<FishTankApp.Models.IntHistoryModel>